# Connected, simply connected, complete riemannian manifold that is locally isometric to $\mathbb{R}^n,S^n, H^n$ is isometric to $\mathbb{R}^n,S^n,H^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

As the title suggests, I am trying to prove that a connected, simply connected, complete riemannian manifold that is locally isometric to $\mathbb{R}^n,S^n, H^n$ is isometric to $\mathbb{R}^n,S^n,H^n$.

The idea of the proof I have consists in extending a local isometry (from $M$ to one of those three spaces, which I will call $X$) $\phi$ defined in a geodesic ball centered at $p \in M$ to all the manifold, and this should be done the following way. Consider a point $q$ that is not in the domain of $\phi$. Then consider a geodesic starting from $p$ at speed $v$ and ending in $q$ at the time $t$. I define $\\psi (q)$ as the point where the geodesic in $X$ starting at $\phi(p)$ with speed $d\phi_{p}(v)$. The question is: how do I continue? I have only the "idea" for what comes next, but I can't put it all together. I know it should be all "well-defined" because of the simple connectedness, and that this $\psi$ that extends $\phi$ should be a local isometry, and surjective. From this fact one should conclude that $\psi$ is an isometry, but I really don't know how to put it all together. There should also be some geodesic balls that "cover" the geodesic from $p$ to $q$, but I really don't have a clue about their role in the proof.

I really don't need a perfectly rigorous proof, I'd be happy to just understand what is going on here.

Comment: You can find a proof for instance in do Carmo's "Riemannian Geometry".

Comment: Gone through the book 4 times and didn't see it. Do you remember if it has a particular name or the section? I cannot find it

Comment: @tommy1996y I guess your confusion comes from the fact that the theorem in do Carmo‘s book (Theorem 4.1 in Chapter 8, p. 163) assumes that the sectional curvature is constant. But remember that curvature is a local property and it is preserved under (local) isometries. Thus, if your manifold is locally isometric to one of those three spaces it has constant sectional curvature. Therefore, you can apply the theorem.

Answer (score 0):

See Theorem 4.1 (in chapter 8) on page 163 of M. Do Carmo "Riemannian Geometry".

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1254684)

Comment: @LukasKofler: A reference to do Carmo's book is not a link in any sense. Since OP has the book, there is no need to reproduce the proof which is quite standard (and quite long as well!).